# No globals have been defined for this package

Tags: java, jboss, drools, jbpm, kie-workbench

I have created 2 rules and one global variable in same drl file inside the jboss wrokbench(business-central).

Rules:

```
package com.myspace.samplerules;
import com.myspace.samplerules.Transaction;

global java.lang.Double disPrice;
global com.myspace.samplerules.Transaction t;

rule "Rule1"
    when
        $t : Transaction(
                amount > 1000
            )
    then
        System.out.println("Executed :- " + drools.getRule().getName());
end

rule "Rule2"
    when
        $t : Transaction(
                amount > disPrice
            )
    then
        System.out.println("Executed :- " + drools.getRule().getName());
end
```

While creating a legacy test scenario I am not able to set value for that global variable. Showing this message while clicking the button to add global variables "Warning: No globals have been defined for this package".

Anybody know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Please include the text of all rules and the error in your post. Pictures of text are no good -- you can't copy-paste from them and they don't show up in search engines (and can't be read by screen readers.) And while you're at it, please include the version of Drools you're using.

Comment: Rules:-
package com.myspace.samplerules;
import com.myspace.samplerules.Transaction;
global java.lang.Double disPrice;
global com.myspace.samplerules.Transaction t;

rule "Rule1"
    when
        $t : Transaction(
                amount > 1000
            )
    then
        System.out.println("Executed :- " + drools.getRule().getName());
end

rule "Rule2"
    when
        $t : Transaction(
                amount > disPrice
            )
    then
        System.out.println("Executed :- " + drools.getRule().getName());
end

Comment: While trying to add global variables in legacy test scenario (in business-central), I got a message like this "Warning: No globals have been defined for this package."

Comment: The [button](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70656735/edit) that says '[Edit]' below your post is for modifying your question with additional information.

Comment: Can you check now?